# Is this possible to make the child dom element to have visible overflow when parent container element has overflow scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

I have a modal component which should have scrollable content.

On that modal component I have a datepicker input, which should popup a datepicker and this popup should be visible even when it is outside of the container component block.

Is this possible to make datepicker component to have visible overflow when the parent has overflow: scroll?

I have tried to use position: absolute but this doesn't help for my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position absolute`

> But you have to remain careful while positioning because `position: absolute` is not positioned w.r.t to parent element in this scenario. You can use another container for `box1` and `position` it `relative`

```css
.box1 {
  width: 180px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried that, it didn't work for me  https://jsfiddle.net/Patlatus/nL960eq8/1/

The element <div lightning-calendar_calendar="" has already position: absolute but this doesn't help

Comment: Maybe it's parent element is `positioned: relative`. As you can try in above snippet by  `positioned: relative` on `box1`. Then the `box2` get hidden inside scroll @Patlatus

Comment: Yes, I have several parent elements with position: relative. If I remove position: relative from every parent element then the datepicker icon is shifted and is not positioned inside the input box